# Can I get a UITextAutocorrection notification?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar

So I have this scenario in my iOS app.

I have a `UISearchbar` and a `UITableView`. The `UISearchbar` has auto correct on, this is important and I want this to remain on.

As the user types in the `UISearchbar`, I automatically start filtering/searching the built in data and present the `UITableView`.  However I keep the table view active so the user can just select an item straight away if they see it.

However imagine the user is searching for an entry called "tesser"

They start typing "tes" then they see "tesser" below so they immediately go to select that entry.

However clicking out the search box means they are accepting the currently auto-correct suggestion of "Tea" - the app then refilters and nothing is displayed and the user is frustrated.
Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: From my experience, once the autocomplete floating work appears, you cannot make it disappear using public API and it will replace any string in the text field. I also cannot think of any app which has autocompletion in its search bar. Consider a slight redesign change.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried turning that off but spell check on and it gives a more pleasing experience but if possible I would like to keep it in.

Comment: So after a weekend trying this is not possible without using private api's - so will just go with spell check and no auto correct.